# BATCH : How to move files with index lower than the highest

Tags: regex, batch-file, directory, filenames

I'm trying to move from dir1 to dir2 the files that have an index lower than the highest index.

I thought I only had to do a simple FOR loop but I have trouble to REGEX the index, and I even have trouble to find a way to compare the index between them

What I tried for the moment (not doing anything) :

```
FOR %%i IN (C:\path\TEST_BAT\*) DO (SET current_path=%%~ni
SET C|findstr /r "ind.{1}" %current_path%
ECHO %C%)
```

Imagine having the set :

- 1234-5678-ind0-example.pdf
- 1234-5678-ind0-example.avi
- 1234-5678-ind0-example.swf
- 1234-5678-indA-example.pdf
- 1234-5678-indA-example.avi
- 1234-5678-indA-example.swf
- 1234-5678-indB-example.pdf
- 1234-5678-indB-example.avi
- 1234-5678-indB-example.swf

I want to run a script that move every file to another directory except the ones with the indB in filename, because this is the highest index at this moment.

Comment: How about using `RoboCopy` directly, _with its `/Mov` and `/XF` options_.

Comment: 1. How does the index look like? is it always a single character, is it a hex. number, or what else is it? 2. Is the prefix and suffix (the stuff before and after `ind?`) always the same? if not, how to treat the files then? 3. Your posted code makes no sense, because you are piping the output of `set C` into the `findstr` command, which is not what you want, I believe; furthermore, `{1}` is not a valid search string for `findstr` (unless you want to take it literally); and it lacks [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding. You are looking to move all files excluding the highest index in example bellow based on the `ind#` status.

- `1234-5678-ind0-example.swf` - **Move File**
- `1234-5678-indA-example.swf` - **Move File**
- `1234-5678-indB-example.swf` - **Don't Move File**

For my solution, we will be extracting the `int#` from the file name, exporting them to a file, sorting said file, then moving the files excluding highest Index. For this, we can simply use `find /V "indB"` however this batch file take dynamic data and creates a solution. It will always take the 3'd `delims` in the `1234-5678-ind0-example` format to compare with, which is what you want.

**MoveButExcludeHighestIndex.bat:**

```
@echo off
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Rem | Configure Directories
Set "MainDirrectory=C:\folder"
Set "MoveToDirrectory=C:\new folder"

Rem | Get All Folders Locations In X Directory
for %%A in ("!MainDirrectory!\*") do (

    Rem | Get Each ind# From %%A
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=-" %%B in ("%%~nA") do (

        Rem Save Results To File
        Echo %%B>> SortNumbers.TEMP

    )
)

Rem | Sort TextFile - Script By dbenham
set "file=SortNumbers.TEMP"
>"%file%.new1" (
  for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%file%") do (
    set "n=000000000000000%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo !n:~-15!
    endlocal
  )
)
>"%file%.new2" sort /r "%file%.new1"
>"%file%" (
  for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=0" %%A in ("%file%.new2") do echo %%A
)
del "%file%.new?"

Rem | Grab Highest Index From TextFile
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('Type SortNumbers.TEMP') do (
    set /a "count+=1"
    set "Line[!count!]=%%A"
)

Rem | Get All Folders Locations In X Directory
for %%A in ("!MainDirrectory!\*") do (

    Rem | Find Files Without Highest Index
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%B in ('Echo %%A^| find /V "!Line[1]!"') do (

        Rem | Move Files
        Set "CopyFile=%%B"
        Move "!CopyFile!" "!MoveToDirrectory!"

    )
)
del "SortNumbers.TEMP"
goto :EOF
```

---

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `find /?`
- So on.